# Handling omitted columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame where the first row contains column names. However, I noticed that there are duplicate column names which got omitted, and I would like to handle this situation properly.

I have a Dataframe like this :

```py
   0   1   2   3   4
0  'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'A'
1   1   2  3   4   5
2  26   7  12  17  22
3   2   8  13  18  23
4  27   9  14  19  24
5   3  10  15  20  25
5  28  29  30  30  30
```

I want to group the values of duplicate columns so the the result appears like this :

```
        
     A    B   C   D 
0   [1,5]   2  3   4   
1   [26,22]  7  12  17
2   [2,23]  8  13  18
...
```

I succeeded in creating a list of duplicate col names indexes

```
first_row = df[0]
 non_unique = first_row[first_row.duplicated()].index.tolist()
```

and combining each row values in a list

```
df['combined']= df[:,non_unique].values.tolist()
```

I'm stuck ,any kind of help is deeply appreciated

Comment: How is your dataframe built? The constructor you're giving will discard the first `A` column since keys have to be unique in a dictionary...

Comment: No that's just an example and I will correct it . In reality I created an empty Dataframe without col names which I populated it from a docx table that's why I said my column names are in the first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid `groupby`, a simple way would be to just *loop* :

```
for col in df.columns[df.columns.duplicated()]:
    df.insert(
        df.columns.tolist().index(col), "tmp", # to insert at the first occurence
        df[[col]].agg(list, axis=1), allow_duplicates=True
    )
    
    df = df.drop(col, axis=1).rename({"tmp": col}, axis=1)
```

Ouptut :

```
print(df)
          A   B   C   D
1    [1, 5]   2   3   4
2  [26, 22]   7  12  17
3   [2, 23]   8  13  18
4  [27, 24]   9  14  19
5   [3, 25]  10  15  20
5  [28, 30]  29  30  30
```